# Free Body Diagram of Perpendicular Forces of Inclined Plane

Tags: forces, free-body-diagram

I've been puzzling over this for a couple days now and I can't find an answer on the internet.

[image]

I have two wedges (inclined planes) facing each other (in the image above) and one of them (the black triangle) is fixed in place and the other can move.  I apply a force `F` to the moving wedge.  **I want to know two things: (1) if my calculation for the force `C` is correct and (2) how to create a free body diagram of this system that represents what is going on.**

Because the wedges act like a simple inclined plane, he force `C` should be equal to the "rise" of the wedges over the "run" (the slope).  In this case, that slope can be found with `1/tan(θ)`.  This means that `C = F / tan(θ)`.  For example if `F = 100 Newtons` and `θ = 30 Degrees` then `C = 173 Newtons`.  **Is this correct?**

**Second, if this is correct, how would I draw a diagram of this where the force vectors work out correctly?**  Most of the typical examples with this type of problem are configured in a different way and never show how force `C` would be derived.

Comment: What is the mass of wdge?

Comment: The mass shouldn't be relevant here.